# "Accept only strictly necessary cookies" button

Tags: feature-request, cookies

Everytime I start the browser on my computer and visit one of the stackexchange websites, I have to click the "customize settings" and "confirm my choices button" on the cookie settings. My PC and internet connection aren't the fastest and the "customize settings" button takes 5 to 10 second before showing the cookie settings menu, at worst it takes more than half a minute for the cookie settings to be shown.

Does stackexchange plan to add "Accept only strictly necessary cookies" for convenience ?

Comment: I marked this post as duplicate , so anyone who want this feature to be added can go visit the associated question and upvote that question.